# .NET Remoting and WCF

Tags: wcf, .net-remoting

I have an old ASP.NET app connecting to a .NET Remoting service. I'd replaced the .NET Remoting service to a WCF service. I have the original WSDL and I've generated a WCF service by the help of svcutil. I don't know whether the client will able to connect and call the WCF service without changing its code.
Is it possible to solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service can be both a remoting service and a WCF service at the same time. 
Just configure it with RemotingServices as usual for remoting.
Then decorate with OperationContract / ServiceContract and construct with ServiceHost and you can create clients for both techniques, just that remoting is TCP only.

Answer (score 1):

WCF and Remoting are different paradigms. So if you changed your Remoting server to .NET WCF service, you will have to change the client code to use the wsdl generated client

look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/migrating-from-net-remoting-to-wcf#Client_Comp. it should not be difficult

Comment: Thank you but I cannot create another new client. But maybe I should create a .NET Remoting service for it. It might be the solution.